# JavaScript, jQuery, Localstorage append items to an array

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var id = 1;
var data = {
    items: {
        id: id,
        html: '<p> Hello</p>',
    }
};

localStorage.setItem("demoitems", JSON.stringify(data));
```

them later on I want to keep the existing values of data.items and append a new array to it like:

```
var id = 2;
var data = {
    items: {
        id: id,
        html: '<p> Hello 2</p>',
    }
};
```

so that the final result would look like:

```
var data = {
    items: {
        id: 1,
        html: '<p> Hello 1</p>',
    },
    items: {
        id: 2,
        html: '<p> Hello 2</p>',
    }
};
```

then I can get it:

```
var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("demoitems"));

$.each(result.items, function(k, v) {
... do loop here
});
```

I have tried something like this:

```
    var newdata = {
        items: {
            id: 2,
            html: '<p> Hello 2</p>',
        }
    };

var olddata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("demoitems"));
newdata.push(newdata, olddata);
```

Comment: So your question is how to append? Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: First of all I don't think you want to have two identical keys (`items`) in the same ison object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't push to Objects, use an Array instead.
And the index in an Object must be unique.

```
var olddata = [
    {
        id: 2,
        html: '<p> Hello 2</p>'
    }
];

localStorage.setItem("demoitems", JSON.stringify(olddata))

var newdata = {
        id: 2,
        html: '<p> Hello 2</p>'
};

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("demoitems"));
data.push(newdata);
localStorage.setItem("demoitems", JSON.stringify(data))

alert( localStorage.getItem("demoitems") );
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/snht4kvy/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't want to have two identical keys (`items`) in the same json object. What you can do is, add your `item` objects to the array in the json object

```
var id = 1;
var data = {
    // array of items
    items: [{
        id: id,
        html: '<p> Hello</p>',
    }]
};
localStorage.setItem("demoitems", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Then you can add new `items` to the array like so:

```
var newitem = {
    id: 2,
    html: '<p> Hello 2</p>',
};

var olddata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("demoitems"));
olddata["items"].push(newitem);
// store the data
localStorage.setItem("demoitems", JSON.stringify(olddata));
```

Comment: It is nearly the same answer as mine.